# Kotlin regex to match line containing specific TODO pattern

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am trying to match a line in Kotlin(JVM) that contains a TODO at some point. My goal is to find if a line contains a TODO but does not contains a related JIRA identifier after.

**Examples**

*Shouldn't match*

```
var x = 3 // TODO JIRA-4
```

*Should match*

```
var x = 3 // TODO
```

I tried:

```
"[\\w]*//([ ]*TODO|[ ]*FIXME)".toRegex().containsMatchIn(myLine).and(!myLine.contains("JIRA"))
```

If possible, I would like to look for both *TODO* and *FIXME*. I am not keen on finding those in a multiline comment.

Comment: I don't know `kotlin` but for regex maybe `\b(TODO|FIXME)\b.+?\bJIRA\b`?

Comment: You said you want to match TODO without JIRA, but your example says you want JIRA to be matched. Do you want JIRA to be matched?
If you want JIRA, you can try `\/\/\ (TODO|FIXME) JIRA`

Comment: @NeelKamath I want to match a line that contains a TODO but not a JIRA project ID after (like in the *Bad* example from the description)

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
listOf("// TODO JIRA-4", "// FIXME JIRA-4", "// TODO hello", "// FIXME hello")
    .filterNot { it.matches(Regex("""\/\/\s*(TODO|FIXME)\s*(JIRA).*""")) }
    .forEach(::println) // prints the last 2 strings
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: I'm unsure what could be edited. The strings and regex are meant to have the code be self-documenting, and the use of a filter on top of the regex naturally follows from the OP's tried method. I don't see the point in explaining what a backslash in regex does. If you find something which can be added to my answer, please feel free to edit it. If you feel the OP asked a coding-service styled question, feel free to vote to close it.